# nodejs mysql pass value from event to another event

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv

I'm using fast csv to parse a csv file

but i need to pass data from the parsed file to an another event to insert into a table in mysql  like this

```
var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data){
         console.log(data);
        // info about file
    })
    .on("end", function(){
         console.log("done");
       // get data from the data event here 
    });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

can this be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an save it into a variable.

```
var d = [];
var csvStream = csv()
    .on("data", function(data){
         console.log(data);
        // info about file
        d = data;
        d.push(data)
    })
    .on("end", function(){
         console.log("done");
       // get data from the data event here 
       d.forEach(function (data) {
         // do something with the data
       })
    });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

Comment: that's my problem i need all the  data

Comment: Oh, i see. See my update. But, why don't you run your process within the data event then ?

Comment: i need data there for an insert